# String in PHP excludes $variable

Tags: php, string, shell, variables

Not sure how to properly describe what I want but after lots of googling I need some help.

I'm using PHP to run some shell commands, one of those shell commands creates a file with some configuration information within it from a string.  This config information has a part that has the string "$uri" so obviously if I I enclose it in double quotes " it tries to call the variable which doesn't exist.  My problem is when I call it in single quotes it's omitting the $uri word entirely... is this normal behavior?

I'll include an example, I'm writing a nginx serverblock file so it's as follows:

```
$nginxhost = 'server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/dev2.host.dev/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name dev2.host.dev;
    include hhvm.conf;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
}';
```

and then executing through ssh2:

```
"echo \"$passsowrd\" | sudo -S sh -c 'echo \"".$nginxhost."\" >> /etc/nginx/sites-available/dev2.host.dev';";
```

Should I wrap the entire $nginxhost with {}? or just the $uri?

Comment: Could you please include a minimal coding example? One with which we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Try `$param = "{$uri}";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For special characters (which can be interpreted as language syntax) you should use the backslash `\` and so `\$uri`